# SqlServer Select Distinct Using Single Column

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I have a column that contains the server in which the action happened as well as the country.  So, for example, the column 'source' would contain 'server001[en-US]'.  What I need to do is get all the distinct country codes listed.

```
ID  SOURCE              STATUS
==============================
1   server001[en-US]    3
2   server002[de-CH]    3
3   server005[en-US]    1
4   server001[tr-TR]    3
```

The ideal query would output

```
en-US
de-CH
tr-TR
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: The ideal database would not store multiple informations in one column ;)

Comment: Agreed Tim... but nothing in the world I work with is ideal :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to play with `substring` and `charindex`.  `charindex` will give you the location of a string within a column and `substring` is pretty obvious.

I did not test this, but something like this should do the trick:

```
select distinct substring(source
     , charindex('[', source)
     , charindex(']', source) - charindex('[', source))
     );
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your help Olivier.  Of course, I had to add the table name, as well as +1 for the from arg and -1 for the to arg to print only the en-US etc.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you a list of distinct country codes:

```
SELECT 
   LEFT(COL, LEN(COL) - 1)
FROM (
    SELECT
        RIGHT(SOURCE, LEN(SOURCE) - CHARINDEX('[', SOURCE)) COL
    FROM TABLE) TBL
```